# org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use

Tags: hibernate, struts2, annotations

I want to create a simple web project app. I am using struts2 and hibernate and I am new to both of this frameworks and I am getting this error:

```
Unable to instantiate Action, org.project.actions.UserAction,  defined for 'saveUser' in namespace '/'An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use 
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:306)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:387)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:186)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:458)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)

root cause

org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use 
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1634)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1589)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1568)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1448)
    org.project.actions.UserAction.(UserAction.java:23)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:119)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:150)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:387)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:186)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:458)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
```

I have tried to use AnnotationConfiguration() to create SessionFactory, but the same error occurs. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who viewed. I've solved the problem. :)

Comment: Could you please make an edit to the previous post or make another one and say that the problem was solved, and also provide your solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my silly mistake. I was using Full Hibernate Plugin. When you use this plugin you don't have to create SessionFactory object for Session object. My mistake was that I forgot to delete SessionFactory object and Session object. :-)

Comment: If you accept your own answer that will indicate it's been solved - no need to add SOLVED to the title.  What makes SO cool is it's not like other forums... what makes S.O. weird is it's not like other forums :)  Welcome to SO.